# Multiple cell select in jqgrid with dynamic columns

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm looking for a feature in `jqgrid` in which i have to select multiple cell and store the corresponding `rowid`, `column name` and `cell value` in a array.

Is that possible, if yes show me a light how?

**Scenario:**

I have to update multiple cell values in a single shot along with those attributes and **FYI**, My columns are `dynamically` created.

If possible please with a demo.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find your question interesting. So I created the demo which demonstrates a possible implementation of selection of cells in jqGrid.

First of all you need to use `beforeSelectRow` which returns `false`. It will suppress the standard highlighting of rows. You can use `.addClass("ui-state-highlight").attr("aria-selected", "true");` to highlight the cell and `.removeClass("ui-state-highlight").removeAttr("aria-selected");` to remove highlighting. The last things which one need to do it to hold the information about the highlighted cells and update it on every highlighting or on removing of highlighting.

Because the rowid have to be unique and the column names have to be different then `rowid + "_" + columnName` have to be unique and it can be used to identify the selected cell. So one could use the map with keys build by `rowid + "_" + columnName`. Such map will hold all required information and it could be easy updated.

After clicking on different cells on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/cellMultiselect.htm) the results will be like on the picture below

[image]

Clicking of previously selected cell unselect it. On click on the "Display Information about selected cells" button one will see full information about all selected rows

The demo uses custom option `mySelection: {}` which will hold the information about cell selection and the following `beforeSelectRow` callback:

```
beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
    var $td = $(e.target).closest("td"),
        iCol = $.jgrid.getCellIndex($td[0]),
        p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam"), // object with all parameters
        cm = p.colModel[iCol],
        key = rowid + "_" + cm.name,
        id = $.jgrid.stripPref(p.idPrefix, rowid);

    if (p.mySelection[key] === undefined || !$td.hasClass("ui-state-highlight")) {
        $td.addClass("ui-state-highlight").attr("aria-selected", "true");
        p.mySelection[key] = {
            id: id,
            colName: cm.name,
            indexOfColumn: iCol,
            htmlValue: $td.html(),
            value: $.unformat.call(this, $td[0], {rowId: rowid, colModel: cm}, iCol)
        };
    } else {
        $td.removeClass("ui-state-highlight").removeAttr("aria-selected");
        delete p.mySelection[key];
    }

    // if the grid has onCellSelect we call it because returning false
    // from beforeSelectRow will prevent the standard processing
    if($.isFunction(p.onCellSelect)) {
        p.onCellSelect.call(this, rowid, iCol, $td.html(), e);
    }

    return false; // swich of the standard selection
}
```

To enumerate all information from `mySelection` I used `for-in` loop:

```
$("#showSelCells").button().click(function() {
    var cellInfo = [], key, item,
        mySelection = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "mySelection");

    for (key in mySelection) {
        item = mySelection[key];
        cellInfo.push("id=" + item.id +
            ", colName=" + item.colName +
            ", indexOfColumn=" + item.indexOfColumn +
            ", value=" + item.value +
            ", htmlValue=" + item.htmlValue);
    }

    alert(cellInfo.join("\n"));
});
```

Comment: The cell needs to be multi-selected only if the "ctrl" key is pressed. Otherwise the row must be selected. Can you please modify this? I tried like    document.body.onclick = function (e) {
                        if (e.ctrlKey) {}} , bu this doesnt work in beforeselect row. Can you help?

Comment: @SanthoshKumar: It's very easy. You need just include `if (!e.ctrlKey) {return true;}` at the beginning of `beforeSelectRow`. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/cellMultiselect_.htm). You can additionally consider to deny cell selection in selected rows.

Comment: Brilliant answer for the question posted. U always rock. Helped me a lot on jqgrid. Thanks a ton!!!

Comment: Being lazy, I'm hoping someone has augmented this solution further - so that a contiguous rectangular block of cells could be easily selected with 2 mouse clicks: between a top corner x1,y1 cell, and a bottom corner selection x2,y2 cell. Anyone?